# Does a javascript library have to be written also in javascript?

Tags: javascript, package

If not, then how is javascript able to run code that is written in a different language?

Comment: You could do a search for "can javascript run x" where `x` is the name of the language.

Comment: A node program can spawn arbitrary processes

Comment: Many JavaScript environments (like in browsers) will have access to APIs that let them run programs which have compiled down to web-assembly. So, this means JavaScript can run Rust code, for example.